# React js/Next js Passing a prop to render a component on a different page

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So I wish to pass a cart object to the Cart Page and render a cart component there, but i am finding a hard time doing it

I have a next app so i can do it through react or through next router/link.
Tried multiple things such as react-dom-router but no luck.
Is there a way to do it without react-dom-router ?

I am fetching the cart as below from commerce.js

```
const fetchCart = async() =>
   {
     setCart(await commerce.cart.retrieve())

   }
```

I have written the logic for add to cart and stuff and it is working completely fine

From the main page I am want to pass this as props to the cartPage so i can use it

```
import React from "react"
import {CartItem, CartContainer } from "../components"

export const CartPage = ({cart}) => {


return(
    <div>

     <CartContainer cart = {cart}/>

    </div>

)
}

export default CartPage
```

I can display the cart perfectly on the same page.
Just want to somehow get the cart object to be accessed on the cart page

Comment: You can't pass data objects via `next/router`. However, you can use React context to make that data available between pages.

Comment: it is not clear what you want to achieve.